# SQL Statement to access data across relationships

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables in my SQL Database:

```
authors:
    name varchar
    id int Primary Key
publications:
    id int Primary Key
    title mediumtext
    year int 
authorsJoinTable: 
    authorId -> Foreign Key to the authors table
    publicationID -> Foreign Key to the publications Table
    sequenceId int
```

I am wondering if it is possible to get all the `publicationIds` from the `authorsJoinTable` 
ordered by `year` descending?
Thanks in Advance,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT publicationID
FROM authorsJoinTable a JOIN publications p
     ON (p.Id = a.publicationId)
ORDER BY p.Year DESC
```

Comment: +1 .. today I learned "AS" syntax is not required between a table identifier and its alias. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT publicationID FROM authorsJoinTable JOIN publications AS P ON P.id = publicationID ORDER BY P.year DESC
```